# in Laravel, can I change mail configuration file name from mail.php to other

Tags: php, laravel, file, email, configuration

Now I am working with Laravel 4.

I want to know one thing.

Can I change mail configuration file name.

It's default name is config/mail.php

I want to have several mail configuration files for switch them.

Is this possible? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change mail configuration file name.

No, you cannot change the mail configuration file name because the Laravel mail package is checking specific config values which resolve to the file `mail.php`.

> I want to have several mail configuration files for switch them. Is this possible?

To have several different mail configurations, you should use different environment files which will set values used in the `mail.php` configuration.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: thanks, Brent, can you explain me with example for multiple configuration.